# Can Actionscript 3 code work on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3

I've got a set of code that, using the .swf file, can be converted to run on either Windows or Macintosh computers. I know .swf files don't work on iPhones but it is my understanding that there is a way to create an AIR file that does work on iPhones.

How do I do it? Or am I sh*t out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AIR can be packaged as a native mobile app for iOS (.ipa) or Android (.apk). You can use the [AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) by itself, or any IDE that supports AIR, such as [Flash Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html), [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html), [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/), [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and probably others that slipped my mind.